# Set Meta Titles in Admin with Variable - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, meta-tags

We have an e-commerce site with many products and to write a title for each one would be very time consuming. Is there a way in the Admin to set the title as `Buy {Product Name} Online` where `{Product Name} is a variable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you want **generic title** for all the product.

**One way**

Either extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` **Block**

**or**

just copy **view.php** from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product`

and following changes

```
if ($title) {
   $headBlock->setTitle($title);
}
else{
   $headBlock->setTitle('Buy '.$product->getName().' Online');
}
```

By this if meta title is set into product it will show it otherwise will set title as generic (`Buy {Product Name} Online`).

**other way**

**write custom script to set metatitle for product. Load entire product collection and set meta title.**

Answer (score 0):

you can try below extension for your requirement

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-seo-for-set-dynamic-meta-data-for-category-and-product-and-meta-title-for-cms-page.html

this extension allows you to create dynamic meta title for all products, also you can set dynamic product name in that meta title.